# NoMethodError in Registrations#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When you try and signup (/users/sign_up), there is an error.

```
NoMethodError in Registrations#new
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb where line #13 raised:
undefined method `user_name' for #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I'm a beginner following a course. My friend also received this error too. I'm not sure how to fix it so here is my code of the registration_controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :user_name, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :user_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

And here is the new.html.erb file of the devise/registrations/new.html.erb:

```
<div class="registration-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="log-in panel">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Create Your Account</h2>
          </div>
          <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, label: false, placeholder: 'Email', input_html: { class: 'input-lg' } %>
              <%= f.input :user_name, required: true, label: false, placeholder: 'User Name', input_html: { class: 'input-lg' } %>
              <%= f.input :password, required: true, label: false, placeholder: 'Password', input_html: { class: 'input-lg' } %>
              <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true, label: false, placeholder: 'Confirm Password', input_html: { class: 'input-lg' } %>
              <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up", class: 'btn-lg btn-info btn-block' %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be user_name column is not available in user table.

Comment: @SampatBadhe So will I have to run rake generate model?

Comment: You have user model already. You just need to add migration to add `user_name` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveModel accept fields which you've defined on your model.
Your `user` object looks like this

```
#<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

You can run a migration and the controller will not complain `NoMethodError` again.

```
rails g migration AddUserNameToUser user_name:string
```

then run,

```
rails db:migrate
```

Comment: If I run rails g AdduserNameToUser user_name:string, it says:R unning via Spring preloader in process 6548
Could not find generator 'AddUserNameToUser'. Maybe you meant 'generator', 'erb:mailer' or 'controller'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.

Comment: My bad, I made a typo. 
It should be `rails g migration AddUserNameToUser user_name:string`